# tabbed info window in fusion table map

Tags: tabs, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I'm trying to get tabbed info windows in a fusion table map. 
I've seen it done **[here](http://www.grasoft.be/mtb/tracks/ShowGPX.htm?gpx=20100523.gpx)**. I've worked on this for weeks and cannot figure out how to make the tabs work. The image below shows an unordered list, followed by the actual data I want broken into each tab, but I can't get the window to recognize the tabs.

**[Sorry, not enough reputation to post image yet.](http://d.pr/i/3RLr)**

I don't know how to use scripts, so there's a good chance that I'm calling the script improperly in the info window.

What code do I put into the info window custom code area? I just need the general structure, don't worry about matching my data fields etc.

Is there something I need to do on the page I publish to?

Thank you so much in advance for any assistance you can give. There is just too much data to house on one tab and I can't think of another way to make this work.

Here's the code I've got (believe it or not it's truncated because there were so many datapoints.

Basically I want three tabs:

```
{template .contents}
<div class='googft-card-view' style='font-family: sans-serif; width: 550px; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden'>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/tabber.js">    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/example.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/example-print.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="print">

<script type="text/javascript">

document.write('<style type="text/css">.tabber{display:none;}<\/style>');

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="tabber">

     <div class="tabbertab">

<h3><a href="#state">State Level Data</a> </h3>
<b>Disaggregated By:</b><br>
<b>Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12):</b> {$data.value['STATE LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12)']}<br><br>

<b>School Level (Elementary/Middle/High):</b> {$data.value['STATE LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: School Level (Elementary/Middle/High)']}<br><br>
<b>Race &/or Ethnicity:</b> {$data.value['STATE LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Race &/or Ethnicity']}<br>
<b>Gender:</b> {$data.value['STATE LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Gender']}<br>
<b>Special Education:</b> {$data.value['STATE LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Special Education']}<br><br>
     </div>

     <div class="tabbertab">

    <h3><a href="#district">District Level Data</a></h3>
<b>Disaggregated By:</b><br>
<b>Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12):</b> {$data.value['DISTRICT LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12)']}<br><br>
<b>School Level (Elementary/Middle/High):</b> {$data.value['DISTRICT LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: School Level (Elementary/Middle/High)']}<br><br>
<b>Race &/or Ethnicity:</b> {$data.value['DISTRICT LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Race &/or Ethnicity']}<br>
<b>Gender:</b> {$data.value['DISTRICT LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Gender']}<br>
<b>Special Education:</b> {$data.value['DISTRICT LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Special Education']}<br><br>
     </div>

     <div class="tabbertab">

    <h3><a href="#school">School Level Data</a></h3>
<b>Disaggregated By:</b><br>
<b>Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12):</b> {$data.value['SCHOOL LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Grade Level (K, 1,&hellip;7,&hellip;10,&hellip;12)']}<br><br>
<b>School Level (Elementary/Middle/High):</b> {$data.value['SCHOOL LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: School Level (Elementary/Middle/High)']}<br><br>
<b>Race &/or Ethnicity:</b> {$data.value['SCHOOL LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Race &/or Ethnicity']}<br>
<b>Gender:</b> {$data.value['SCHOOL LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Gender']}<br>
<b>Special Education:</b> {$data.value['SCHOOL LEVEL REPORTING Disaggregated by: Special Education']}<br><br>
     </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
{/template}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  To make a tabbed infoWindow you need to add a custom infowindow to a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer) on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) map.

Comment: Are you trying to get the tabs to display it the FusionTables UI?  You will probably need to do this on a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) map (as I said before)